# swift - NSPredicate and Context Save is not working well

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, nspredicate

I have a function that checking core data. if doesn't exist it should write to in it(but its not working in that way) SoundItems is an array that contains favorited objects and mainArray is the array that contains real objects;

```
   @IBAction func Favori(_ sender: Any) {
        // save core data
        let app = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = app.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let newSound = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Sounds", in: context)
        let sound = NSManagedObject(entity: newSound!, insertInto: context)
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Sounds")

        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "soundName = %@", soundArray[soundIndex].deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent)
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
        do {
         let fetchResults = try context.fetch(fetchRequest) as? [Sounds]
              if fetchResults!.count > 0 {

                print("already favd")
            }
         else {

               sound.setValue(soundArray[soundIndex].deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent, forKey: "soundName")
                    try context.save()
                        soundItems.append(sound)
                            print(sound)

            }
        }

        catch {
        print(error)
        }
    }
```

and here is the code that listing the core data;

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")! as UITableViewCell
    let sound = soundItems[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = sound.value(forKey: "soundName") as? String

    return cell

}
```

I tried to run the code in debug mode and it works fine when there is no duplicated core data and adds into the tableView list. **But here is the situation; when core data exist(fetchResults!.count > 0) still adding in the tableview as nil label.text but always adds the item of mainArray[0]**

Comment: You are **first inserting** a new object (without a name) and **then checking** if the item for a specific name exists. Think carefully about your workflow. Is this what you want? Shouldn't you **first check** and  **then** (conditionally) **insert**.

Comment: Even if inserts to the core data it won't append to the soundItems array. Because TableView fetching from array of soundItems ? but when I check how many items in soundItems in tableViewController.swift file it seems append to it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand truly saving to core data thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if the sound is in the favorites and if not add a new sound you have to change the order of the steps

```
@IBAction func Favori(_ sender: Any) {
    // save core data
    let app = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = app.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let fetchRequest : NSFetchRequest<Sounds> = Sounds.fetchRequest()
    let favName = soundArray[soundIndex].deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "soundName = %@", favName)
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
    do {
        let fetchResults = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        if fetchResults.isEmpty {
            let newSound = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Sounds", into:context) as! Sounds
            newSound.soundName = favName
            try context.save()
            soundItems.append(newSound)
            print(newSound)
        }
        else {
             print("already favd")
        }
    }

    catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

It's recommended to name entities in singular form (`Sound`).

Comment: Oooh, I see now clearly. Very much thanks you are the best.

Answer (score 0):

@vadian had the point. Why did you insert a new sound before fetching the data?

```
 let newSound = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Sounds", in: context)
 let sound = NSManagedObject(entity: newSound!, insertInto: context)
```